# Can I Delete migrations models django?

Tags: mysql, django, migration

i am creating my site with django and MySQL (all are latest versions), my data base plan was change. now i want to edit my MySQL database. the project is still testing in face i don't need any data of the database. I'm new for python, Django with MySQL. please help with this.
thank you

Comment: Hello, SO is not a place to ask "Do it for me". Your question seems to be incomplete. Kindly add more details  of your research or what have you done so far

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete all files in `migrations` folder except `__init__.py`
2. Delete database file `db.sqlite3`
3. Execute `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Execute `python manage.py migrate`
   Now you should have new database file created and initial migrations applied for each application.

Comment: I haven't read the question carefully so this answer is only relevant for sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

You can follow next steps if you don't need any data in your DB

1. Delete all migrations files (Save them just in case)
2. Create new database
3. Set new database in `settings.py`
4. `makemigrations` and `migrate` on new database